# Display review queue length in the actual review page

Tags: feature-request, review, review-queue

I would like to see how many pending reviews are left in the queue while I review. For long queues like the *Close votes* this makes no difference, but it would be nice to know in short queues whether I am close to reach the end or whether there is still a bunch of work to do.

So my request: A small indicator next to the `Review | First Posts    filter` text at the top of every review page (First post queue in this example) that shows the current queue length like this: `23 posts left`

What do you think?